# How to create registration form so that when published, all data will go to a database?

Tags: html, database, amazon-web-services

I am currently in the process of creating a website, and I am now in the phase of trying to create a registration database. Currently, I have the databse running through localhost, using phpmyadmin and mySQL. But, when I publish the website itself, I want for each person, when they register, for their information to go to a database. I am quite new to database design and development, so I was wondering about how I should go about doing this? At the current moment, given its setup, I am sure that there will be an error caused if someone else tries to submit their information into the registration page because their computer is not holding the server. How may I resolve this? I hope that my question was clear...

I already have php code that sends the registration info to the database, but I know that it will only work on my computer.

Comment: How does it relate to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

- The browser runs on the user's computer
- The HTTP server runs on a hosting computer
- The database server runs on a hosting computer

These can all be the same computer (and in the development environment you've described: they are).

When you deploy it to a production environment, the HTTP server will be public facing. The user's browser can connect to it from anywhere* on the Internet.

Since the HTTP server runs the PHP which talks to the database server, it doesn't matter that the database isn't stored on the end user's computer.

---

`*` Issues such as the great firewall of china aside

Comment: Thanks for the help. So since my php script connects to host "localhost", how do I be sure that the connection is being established to my computer only?

Comment: localhost will be whatever the computer running the http server considers to be localhost